# I am little bit confused with the error getting gradle , can anyone solve this?

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for arm64 in debug mode...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timeout of 120000 reached waiting for exclusive access to file: /Users/DIGITAL_VASANTH/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-7.6.3-all/aocdy2d2z8kodnny3rsumj8i8/gradle-7.6.3-all.zip
at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:61)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
[!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network.

I have tried to reflect the code in app emulator, but this error had raised while running the code in vscode

Comment: tried flutter doctor ?

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens because of broken `gradle` files/installation, you need to delete the `.gradle` folder and run the flutter app again.

**Windows**: `C:\Users\<user>\.gradle`

**Mac**: `/home/<user>/.gradle`

Do not disconnect your device, it might take a little longer because gradle dependencies will be downloaded again.

Answer (score 0):

### Check Gradle Version In The Project in this Project Path

> android/build.gradle

---

and change it to gradle installed in your PC in this Path

---

> C:/Users/DIGITAL_VASANTH/.gradle/wrapper/dists

---

Then open Project Terminal And type This

```
flutter clean 

flutter pub get
```